# Missing required fields when creating Cloud Build Trigger using Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to create `Cloud Build Trigger` using `Deployment Manager` but when running the `gcloud` command I get

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create example-config --config deployment.yaml --preview

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1682857809168-5fa8cddec46b3-3b41bddf-ca76e739]: errors:
- code: INVALID_CONFIG
  message: 'Invalid config files: Template fetching failed: Type gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1
    is not a valid template type, missing required fields.'
```

I checked the documentation but I can't figure out what required field is missing
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers#BuildTrigger

**deployment.yaml**

```
imports:
  - path: build-trigger.jinja

resources:
  - name: hello-world-triggers
    type: build-trigger.jinja
    properties:
      name: hello-world
```

**build-trigger.jinja**

```
resources:
- name: {{ properties["name"] }}-staging
  type: gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1
  properties:
    resourceName: projects/{{ env["project"] }}/locations/global/triggers/{{ properties["name"] }}-staging
    description: GCF {{ properties["name"] }} staging
    name: {{ properties["name"] }}-staging
    triggerTemplate:
      projectId: {{ env["project"] }}
      repoName: functions
      branchName: ^master$
      invertRegex: true
    includeFiles:
    - {{ properties["name"] }}/**
    filename: {{ properties["name"] }}/cloudbuild.yaml
    eventType: REPO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two mistakes:

- the type should be `gcp-types/cloudbuild-v1:projects.triggers` as explained https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types
- the `includeFiles` should be named `includedFiles`